# Setup small retention_ms in kafka 0.9 is not working

Tags: apache-kafka

I'd like to setup small `retention_ms` as 1200000 to remove initial dirty load sometimes.

The json is totally correct and because it doesn't work, additionally I also try to setup other parameters. However, my consumer still can fetch the data which exists two weeks before.

```
 {"config": {"segment.ms": "1200000", "retention.ms": "1200000", "cleanup.policy": "delete", "segment.jitter.ms": "1200000", "delete.retention.ms": "1200000", "min.cleanable.dirty.ratio": "0.01"}, "version": 1}
```

To sum up, I'm wondering the default retention.ms is 7 days but my consumer can reach the data exist in 7 days with autooffser.reset as earliest,

and what would be the reason that kafka ignores my retention.ms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the source code https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/admin/AdminUtils.scala#L492 ,

Kafka updates the config of topic by storing the notification of changes in zookeeper. So the problem was storing the config json in `/config/topics` is not enough, you need to store the json in `/config/changes` in zookeeper as well.